# Solution: How to make a transparent Text over Image

Tags: html, css

**Solution :** Gives CSS - Transparent Fonts. Any Letters you Want. It's from : http://lea.verou.me/2012/05/text-masking-the-standards-way/ which some editing.

```css
/**
 * Text masking — The SVG way
 */

svg {
 width: 7em; height: 3em;
 font: 900 500%/1.2 'Arial Black', sans-serif;
}

text { fill: url(#wood); }
```

```html
<svg>
<defs>
 <pattern id="wood" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="240" height="300" >
  <image xlink:href="http://hd.wallpaperswide.com/thumbs/girl_beach_background-t2.jpg" width="400" height="400" />
 </pattern>
</defs>
<text y="2em">Nice Beach</text><text y="3em">Isnt't It</text>
</svg>
```

Code: Just change the < text.. >Change this< /text > to other words.

HTML

```
<svg>
<defs>
    <pattern id="wood" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="240" height="300" >
        <image xlink:href="http://hd.wallpaperswide.com/thumbs/girl_beach_background-t2.jpg" width="400" height="400" />
    </pattern>
</defs>
<text y="2em">Nice Beach</text><text y="3em">Isnt't It</text>
</svg>
```

CSS:

```
/**
 * Text masking — The SVG way
 */

svg {
    width: 7em; height: 3em;
    font: 900 500%/1.2 'Arial Black', sans-serif;
}

text { fill: url(#wood); }
```

Comment: Self answered questions are fine but they must be presented in the Q&A format. Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer and format your question as a question and an answer.

Comment: You want this effect with text and css?

Comment: Where is question?

Comment: The Question is how do you edit text on the fly?

Comment: why did you edit it ?

Comment: Did you know how to do this @AbhishekPandey

Comment: Just change the text inside the <text> </text> .. The question is still confusing

Comment: _"Since you guys don't know this"_ - that's quite some statement. And quite rude.

Comment: https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/aONdzJ without using svg

Comment: Yes! Stack Exchange has always explicitly encouraged users to answer their own questions. If you have a question that you already know the answer to, and you would like to document that knowledge in public so that others (including yourself) can find it later, it's perfectly okay to ask and answer your own question on a Stack Exchange site.

Comment: So i did that? And people are still pissed?

Comment: @Rachel I still don't see a question

Comment: @Rachel no one is pissed. Its just the way you have asked the question here is wrong. SO is used as question answer website where a solution is given to the problems which can be used in future by other users who are facing the same problem.. But I still don't get your question.. Or its the answer :P

Comment: @Rachel That doesn't matter, but this isn't any question.

Comment: Well, like i said. I thought of question after typing this. This is mostly a self - answered question. And people are angry because they don't you can do that here. Anyhow, my Question is How do you make a image behind the text? Like this https://snag.gy/d5KQDX.jpg

Comment: Another Question I had im mind is how you make a box where you can edit the text written in the svg ... Here is an example : https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_html_replacewith

Comment: @Rachel now thats a good question .. You must have used it in your question not in comment

Comment: It's great that you are giving us the benefit of your knowledge. It looks like you put the answer in two places. Would you mind editing the question to make it more obvious what you're solving?

Comment: Well im still trying to solve the question how to make the image i posted above. I also trying to solve the question how to make a box where I can edit the svg text live on a website.

Answer (score 0):

With css. It's easy:

```
div {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

div p { 
    opacity: 1.0;
}
```

Just change `div` and `p` for whatever you need.

Comment: You dont comprehend what I have done here. Its basicly removing the need to edit a png in photoshop to mask out the text. The svg is masking out the text itself.

Comment: @Rachel Let's see if I *comprehend* what you mean. You want the text to basically be a hole so you can see background under the div it belongs to?

Answer (score -2):

```css
/**
 * Text masking — The SVG way
 */

svg {
 width: 7em; height: 3em;
 font: 900 500%/1.2 'Arial Black', sans-serif;
}

text { fill: url(#wood); }
```

```html
<svg>
<defs>
 <pattern id="wood" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="240" height="300" >
  <image xlink:href="http://hd.wallpaperswide.com/thumbs/girl_beach_background-t2.jpg" width="400" height="400" />
 </pattern>
</defs>
<text y="2em">Nice Beach</text><text y="3em">Isnt't It</text>
</svg>
 Run code snippet
```

Comment: any explanation along with the answer  _(of a clear question)_ will be usefull, a chunk of code on itself is not. Welcome to SO :)